# Why am I getting this DatabaseService and initialData error when coding my app in Flutter in Dart in Andriod Studio?

Tags: database, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return StreamProvider<QuerySnapshot>.value(
      value: DatabaseService().users,
      initialData: null,
       child: Scaffold(
```

I'm getting an error under DatabaseService() which says 'he named parameter 'uid' is required, but there's no corresponding argument.' but I don't think I need that uid parameter. This is my Stream in my database file:

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> get users {
   return usersCollection.snapshots();
}
```

And then under initialData: null, I'm getting an error which says 'The argument type 'Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'QuerySnapshot<Object?>'.' What should I do to fix both these errors?

Comment: can you try edit to ```StreamProvider<QuerySnapshot?>``` ?

Comment: How do I fix the database error, it's asking me to include a uid parameter but I don't think I need that and I don't know how to get around that?